# On load, jump to anchor within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

Let's say I have the following page:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='foo' style='scroll:auto;height:400px'>
      // content, content, content...
      <div id='bar'></div>
      // content, content, content...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What jQuery (or vanilla Javascript) can I use so that when the page loads, it jumps to #bar **only within the div#foo** (and not the entire page)? I don't need a fancy animation or scrolling, I just want #bar to be at the top of the div on page load.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery solution (assumes all elements are positioned somehow)

```
$('#foo').scrollTop($('#bar').position().top);
```

**EDIT**

Side note: Make sure you set `padding-top` on `bar` and not `margin-top` if you want to put some space between `foo` and `bar` once its scrolled.

**EDIT** DOM Solution (works whether elements have been positioned or not, see @cobbals answer for a jQuery equivalent):

```
document.getElementById('foo').scrollTop += document.getElementById('bar').offsetTop - document.getElementById('foo').offsetTop
```

Comment: doesn't work if containing div doesn't align with top of page

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work if div doesn't align with the top of the page?

Comment: scrolls to the wrong place for me if some text is placed before div #foo

Comment: All the values being read and set are defined relative to foo as the parent element (`scrollTop()` and `position().top`) so anything outside of foo shouldn't have an effect.

Comment: maybe it's a bug in safari then

Comment: @cobbal...check to make sure you closed all your `div` tags when you tested it, and that you are using `$('#bar').position().top` and not `$('#bar').offset().top`

Comment: Ah.  that would explain it.  I can't test it right now so it would be nice if you could verify that it is correct.

Comment: Huh.  For some reason its showing the offset and position both as zero in your test.  I'll add a non jQuery solution that should def work.

Comment: Right, so I figured out what the cause of all confusion was.  The jQuery solution I first posted depends on `foo` being positioned somehow, either `relative` or `absolute`.  The second DOM solution I posted will work regardless of positioning, as long as the `foo` hasn't already been scrolled.  I've edited the DOM solution based of @cobbal's jQuery solution to account for the `scrollTop` of `foo` being non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#foo").scrollTop($("#foo #bar").position().top);
})
```

Comment: Nice. Since #bar is an id and you don't technically need to worry about duplicates, the inner contextual selector is unnecessary. Neat to see someone thinking in that direction anyway.

Comment: $('#bar').scrollTop() would give you the scrollTop property bar, which would be 0, which would do nothing.

Comment: You're all over it Ryan. Many thanks for pointing out my obvious oversight as this is an extremely complicated question/solution.

Comment: Ha. Sure thing. Check the other solutions and comment threads though  because there seems to be an unexpected result when `foo` contains non block elements before `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

long and unwieldily, there is probably a way to shorten it, but it gets to the right place every time.

```
$("#foo").scrollTop($("#foo").scrollTop() +
                    $("#bar").offset().top -
                    $("#foo").offset().top);
```

Comment: Are you sure? Test it in your page.  It runs into the same problem by jQuery solution did when bar has non block elements before it in that `$('#bar').offset().top` returns a different value than `document.getElementById('bar').offsetTop`.

Comment: they do return different values, but `$('#foo').scrollTop() + $("#bar").offset().top` is the same as `document.getElementById('bar').offsetTop` (not exactly sure why, but it seems to work)

Comment: Your answer has the opposite problem as my original one. It functions as expected only if `bar` is the first `block` element in `foo`. Put `block` element like a `<p>` before your `bar` in your test and try your answer to see what I mean.

Comment: can't seem to reproduce it, still works fine for me (firefox and safari) if I replace with `<p>content...</p>`. http://jsbin.com/ofaqa

Comment: Right.  So I figured out what was causing all the confusion, check out the final edit to my answer.