# jQuery move to anchor location on page load

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I have a simple page setup such as:

```
<div id="aboutUs">
  About us content...
</div>
<div id="header">
  Header content...
</div>
```

When the page loads, I need the page to automatically scroll down (no animation needed) to `#header`, so the user cannot see the About Us div unless they scroll up.

`#aboutUs` has a fixed height, so there isn't any need for any variables to determine the height or anything... if that's even needed.

I came across [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708842/on-load-jump-to-anchor-within-a-div) and tried to modify some of the answers for my situation, but nothing seemed to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer to related question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905867/how-to-scroll-to-specific-item-using-jquery

Answer (score 131, accepted):

#### Description

You can do this using jQuery's `.scrollTop()` and `.offset()` method

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/RbxVJ/2/)

#### Sample

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#header").offset().top );  
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/RbxVJ/2/)**
- [jQuery.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
- [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... it's exactly what I need except I can't get it to work on my end. If it makes any difference, I'm working with a pre-coded storefront (so I can't change the structure) and the About Us div is placed before the header using the .insertBefore method. Would that be causing it not to work? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my late respone, i was in the kitchen ;) It looks like you are new to jQuery, right ? You have to wait till the DOM is fully builded. My answer and fiddle is updated. Hope this helps, if not ask me again.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is this better than `document.getElementById("header").scrollIntoView()`?

Answer (score 27):

Did you tried JQuery's `scrollTo` method? http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Or you can extend JQuery and add your custom mentod:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
 scrollToMe: function () {
   var x = jQuery(this).offset().top - 100;
   jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x}, 400);
}});
```

Then you can call this method like:

```
$("#header").scrollToMe();
```

Comment: Cool function:) You can let the function take the animation speed as a variable aswell. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Put this right before the closing Body tag at the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
    if (location.hash) {
        location.href = location.hash;
    }
</script>
```

jQuery is actually not required.

Comment: Given that "no animation needed", I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Wow, this just totally saved my bacon on an unrelated matter. Many, many thanks Chris :-)