# Navigating from div tags within the same page using buttons?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button

I am developing a website using asp.net/C#
I want to create a button that can save user data then move to a div tag at the same page.

I already did the saving part, but how do I make the same button to navigate to a different div tag within the same page?
some people use the response.redirect method to navigate to a different page. I want to navigate to a div tag within the same page. For example:
`<a href="#experience">Experience</a>`
after I press that it will take me to:
`<div class="panel" id="experience">`

I want to do the same but with button that can do both that and saving to a DB. As I said, I already did the saving part.

I tried this:
`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save & Continue" OnClientClick="#experience" OnClick="Button1_Click" />`
But it didn't work.

any ideas? I am trying to access that div tag from code behind

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like some of the details are missing from your question.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some sort of javascript driven anchor scrolling. I would advise to look at this [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884230/jquery-move-to-anchor-location-on-page-load) excepted answer, providing you make use of or include jQuery in your site.

Comment: sorry just edited that

Answer (score 0):

If this is WebForms and you don't want to use javascript, then, after you do the save, you can do a Response.Redirect to the same url, but with the anchor tag, e.g. Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx#experience").

This really depends on the rest of your code though. I suggest posting the relevant parts of your code behind so that we can better see what you have done. Also, don't try to avoid javascript - it is too useful to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a `Focus` method that can be applied to the following ASP.NET server controls:

- `Button`
- `LinkButton`
- `ImageButton`
- `CheckBox`
- `DropDownList`
- `FileUpload`
- `HyperLink`
- `ListBox`
- `RadioButton`
- `TextBox`

At the end of your `Button1_Click` event handler code-behind, add something along this lines of this:

```
TextBoxExperience.Focus();
```

*Note* - The `TextBox` control with ID of `TextBoxExperience` control would be inside of the `experience` `DIV`.